# UITableView not scrolling in UICollectionVew

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have UITableView in UITableViewCell. And my UITableView not scrolling. How can I fix it? If need some part of code - no problem!

Comment: `UITableView` inside a `UITableViewCell`? Or `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: UITableView inside .xib file and UICollectionViewCell load from .xib file.
--> UITableView inside UITableViewCell